# Making an li active according query string value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am programming a website with ASP.NET MVC using C#. I have `ul li,` with a few tabs, I want to get the query string and check the value, according to the query string value, I want to make a `li` active

```
 <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link @{Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "newest" ? 'active' : ''}" href="~/products?CatId=@Context.Request.Query["CatId"]&ordering=newest" role="tab" aria-controls="newest" aria-selected="true">newest</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link @{Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "MostVisited" ? 'active' : ''}"  href="~/products?CatId=@Context.Request.Query["CatId"]&ordering=MostVisited" role="tab" aria-controls="MostVisited" aria-selected="false">MostVisited</a>
  </li>
                   
   <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link @{Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "Most-Rank" ? 'active' : ''}" href="~/products?CatId=@Context.Request.Query["CatId"]&ordering=Most-Rank" role="tab" aria-controls="Most-Rank" aria-selected="false">Most-Rank</a>
   </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link @{Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "cheapest" ? 'active' : ''}" href="~/products?CatId=@Context.Request.Query["CatId"]&ordering=cheapest" role="tab" aria-controls="cheapest" aria-selected="false">cheapest</a>
    </li>
```

but it doesn't work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to replace `@{Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "MostVisited" ? 'active' : ''}"` by `@(Context.Request.Query["ordering"] == "MostVisited" ? 'active' : '')"` ?

If it is Razor template, then the right syntax is `@(expression)`, not `@{expression}`.

Regards